# Change ios display and or accessibility settings in app

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm after an app that will essentially be able to change a number of display/accessibility settings on an iPad based on preconfigured profiles.

I would like to know if this is at all possible, and if so so could you point me in the direction of the API Docs or whatever that will show me what can and can't be done.

From my research it seems that an app can not change ios settings (but can read certain things, such as whether the device has been muted?), but I would appreciate it if somebody could confirm or point me to some sort of work around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change an accessibility profile within iOS (as of iOS8) but it is possible to detect if accessibility is enabled from the iOS SDK, e.g.

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning();
```

will tell you if the user has VoiceOver (Apple's screen reader) running.